# Creating a text or ini files in Inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

Can you please help me in creating a text file or an ini file by using inno setup.Is it can be done using pascal way of creating the text files

Answer (score 2):

There is built in support for manipulating INI files

```
[INI]
Filename: "MyProg.ini"; Section: "InstallSettings"; Flags: uninsdeletesection
Filename: "MyProg.ini"; Section: "InstallSettings"; Key: "InstallPath"; String: "{app}"
```

Just look up `[ini]` in the help file.

Answer (score 1):

Plain text files can be created from `[Code]` using the `SaveStringToFile()` function.